# How to build invertible Toeplitz matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, random-matrices, toeplitz-matrices

Toeplitz matrices are matrices where each descending diagonal is constant.
A $n\times n$ Toeplitz matrix can generated by a sequence $(c_{1}\ldots c_{2n-1})$.
For example, here is a $5\times5$ matrix:

$$
\left(\begin{array}{ccccc}
c_{5} & c_{6} & c_{7} & c_{8} & c_{9}\\
c_{4} & c_{5} & c_{6} & c_{7} & c_{8}\\
c_{3} & c_{4} & c_{5} & c_{6} & c_{7}\\
c_{2} & c_{3} & c_{4} & c_{5} & c_{6}\\
c_{1} & c_{2} & c_{3} & c_{4} & c_{5}
\end{array}\right)
$$

Let us define *k-periodic Toeplitz matrices* as Toeplitz matrices
generated by a sequence $(c_{1}\ldots c_{2n-1})$ such that $c_{i+k}=c_{i}$
for all $i<2n-k$. For example, a $6$-periodic $5\times5$ Toeplitz
matrix would look like this:

$$\left(\begin{array}{ccccc}
c_{5} & c_{6} & c_{1} & c_{2} & c_{3}\\
c_{4} & c_{5} & c_{6} & c_{1} & c_{2}\\
c_{3} & c_{4} & c_{5} & c_{6} & c_{1}\\
c_{2} & c_{3} & c_{4} & c_{5} & c_{6}\\
c_{1} & c_{2} & c_{3} & c_{4} & c_{5}
\end{array}\right)$$

**My question is**: for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and any $k\in\{n+1\ldots2n-1\}$,
does there exist *invertible* k-periodic Toeplitz matrices and
can we proove it ?

I have done a lot of numerical experiments (I tried all values of $n$ up to 60), and up to now I have
found ways to build these invertible matrices, but with no guarantee.

- For all $n\in\{3\ldots60\}$ and all periods $k\in\{n+1\ldots2n-1\}$,
  choosing $c_{i}=i^{th}$ *prime number* induces invertible k-periodic Toeplitz matrices
- For the same values of $n$ and $k$, choosing $c_{i}\sim\mathcal{N}(0,1)$
  also induces invertible k-periodic Toeplitz matrices
- For $n>7$ choosing $c_{i}\sim bernoulli(0.5)$ induces invertible
  k-periodic Toeplitz matrices with high probability

My best guess would be choosing normally distributed $c_{i}$ would be the way to go to get a theorem, but I don't really know. There are lots of results on invertible random circulant matrices, but I don't see how to translate them in my case. Does anyone have a clue ?

Comment: Isn't the identity matrix of this type for whatever $k$?